# Saving states of toggle button in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I know about recycling rows in a listview. I have a listview with toggle buttons. I'm saving the states of the toggle buttons in a SparseBooleanArray as lot of posts suggest. My problem is the toggle button row gets on and off on scroll anyway. In my code I have saved the state of togglebutton and their respective position in the array and them I get their states from the same array.
Thanks.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolderBrandAvailability holder;
        if(row == null){
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(con);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //viewHolderBrandAvailability = new ViewHolderBrandAvailability();
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_availability_listview, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolderBrandAvailability();
            holder.brandNameTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.brandAvailabilityNameText);
            holder.radioGroup = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.brandAvailable);
            /*viewHolderBrandAvailability.unavailableRadioBtn = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.brandUnavailable);*/

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolderBrandAvailability) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.radioGroup.setTag(position);
        holder.radioGroup.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));

        holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){

                    selectedBrandStatus.put(((BrandAvailability)list.get(position)).getBrand_id(), "Yes");

                }else {
                    selectedBrandStatus.put(((BrandAvailability)list.get(position)).getBrand_id(), "No");

                }
                mCheckStates.put((Integer) compoundButton.getTag(), isChecked);
            }
        });


        String brandTitle = ((BrandAvailability)list.get(position)).getBrand_title();
        holder.brandNameTextView.setText(brandTitle);
        //holder.radioGroup.setChecked();
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolderBrandAvailability {
        private TextView brandNameTextView;
        private ToggleButton radioGroup;
        //RadioButton unavailableRadioBtn;
        //int position;
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem that the `ToggleButton` is in the wrong checked state, or is the problem that `selectedBrandStatus` says "yes" when it should say "no" (or vice versa)?

Comment: The togglebutton is in the wrong state.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, I see nothing that indicates a problem with the checked state of the `ToggleButton` changing on scroll. In fact, I created my own adapter to test out your code, and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Often, people run into a similar issue because they don't realize that the `OnCheckedChangeListener` they set in one call to `getView()` will stick around during the next call to `getView()`, and so the `setChecked()` call winds up triggering it. However, in your case, you're using `compoundButton.getTag()` to determine the index into the `mCheckStates` array, so there's no problem here.

That being said, you **are** using the `getView()` `position` argument for other operations in your listener, and this *will* cause the issue I described above.

```
selectedBrandStatus.put(((BrandAvailability)list.get(position)).getBrand_id(), "Yes");
```

Imagine `getView()` is called for the very first time, for position 0. Your code runs, and assigns the listener. You wind up checking the `ToggleButton` at position 0, so you call `selectedBrandStatus.put(list.get(0).getBrand_id(), "Yes")`. Now you scroll the list until this view is recycled: `getView()` is called again and this view is passed as `convertView`. Let's call this position 20. Your listener is still in place, so when the `ToggleButton` is unchecked by `holder.radioGroup.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(20, false))`, it is triggered again. Now it will overwrite the previous `"Yes"` with `"No"`, since the listener was created using `position` = 0.

You can just change all of the indexes in your listener to be `(Integer) compoundButton.getTag()` and that will fix this problem.